# Closing app on iOS power button switch off

Tags: ios

I am creating an iPad application on iOS5.0. I need it to close down if the user is in the app and presses the power off button on the iPad. The user would need to restart the app once he clicks the power button. How should I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this key

> Application does not run in background=NO

in `App-info.plist` file, then add `exit(0);` to `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Comment: this causes the application to run in the background. I need to actually terminate the application

Comment: sorry set the value to YES. its default value is NO so you have to change it to YES so that you application does not run in background

Comment: i did that, but the application still remains active when the power off button is clicked off and then switched on. the application does not close

Comment: ok then write exit(0); in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method and try i think this helps you

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :-) i set the Application does not run in background plist attribute to NO so that it runs in the background. And when the  power off button is clicked the application delegate receives the callback for applicationDidEnterBackground and there I've put exit(0) so the application terminates whenever it enters background which does not happen when the maps location popup message appears but appears when the application goes to the background when another application is opened or the power button is clicked off.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this....

UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to your Info.plist

Comment: tried this... in iOS 5.0 its the plist attribute Application does not run in background. I set it to YES. however, if the application screen is on and i power off they pad and then power it back on, then the application screen continues to be shown. The applicationWillTerminate is not called at all

Answer (score 0):

You can exit(0) in the applicationWillResignActive method of your delegate but it will kill the app if there is a phone call or something. 
And apple will block it.

Comment: I cannot do that because I'm showing a web view in the application and if the user goes to the maps section in google then the message that comes up saying whether the app can use current location also causes the applicationWillResignActive method to be called on my app's delegate. But in this case, I need to still keep the application active

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: one part of my application is a browser application that shows google.com in a UiWebview. when the user clicks on the power button, it should close down the app. however, I've noticed that when the user clicks on the maps, an alert is shown asking whether his current location can be used. When this alert shows up, I've noticed that  the applicationwillresignactive method is called on the delegate, so putting an exit(0) there would make the app exit when the user is responding to this alert too.

Comment: I think the popup shows only once so you could do a test before your exit(0) to see if the user already authorized maps.